XLS-R code is running without giving any output, Is there anything I can do to my code
I am using XLS-R for deepfake audio detection on a sample of 1000 audios in 5 different languages but it has been running without giving any output or even an error. How should I fix it? Also would you suggest me using a different model instead of this. I want to work with a pre trained model for model comparison.
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import torch
from transformers import Wav2Vec2Processor, Wav2Vec2Model
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from tensorflow.keras.layers import BatchNormalization, Input, Dense, Dropout, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
from tensorflow.keras.utils import to_categorical
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report, confusion_matrix
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import librosa


# Define the audio folder path

    audio_folder_path = r"C:\Users\INDIA\Desktop\dissertation\CVoiceFake_small\sample\mixed"

# Load the pre-trained XLS-R model and processor with specified tokenization behavior

    processor = Wav2Vec2Processor.from_pretrained("facebook/wav2vec2-base-960h",       clean_up_tokenization_spaces=True)
    model_wav2vec = Wav2Vec2Model.from_pretrained("facebook/wav2vec2-base-960h")
    
    def extract_features(file_name):
    try:
        # Ensure resampling to 16kHz
        audio_path = os.path.join(audio_folder_path, f"{file_name}.mp3")
        audio, sample_rate = librosa.load(audio_path, sr=16000)
    
        # MFCC features
        mfccs = librosa.feature.mfcc(y=audio, sr=sample_rate, n_mfcc=40)
        mfccs_scaled = (np.mean(mfccs.T, axis=0) - np.mean(mfccs)) / np.std(mfccs)
    
        # Mel spectrogram features
        mel_spectrogram = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=audio, sr=sample_rate)
        mel_spectrogram_db = librosa.power_to_db(mel_spectrogram, ref=np.max)
        mel_spectrogram_scaled = (np.mean(mel_spectrogram_db.T, axis=0) -     np.mean(mel_spectrogram_db)) / np.std(mel_spectrogram_db)
    
        # Pitch frequency
        pitches, magnitudes = librosa.piptrack(y=audio, sr=sample_rate)
        pitch_freq = np.mean([pitches[magnitudes[:, i].argmax(), i] for i in range(magnitudes.shape[1])]) if magnitudes.size > 0 else 0
    
        # Onset strength
        onset_strength = librosa.onset.onset_strength(y=audio, sr=sample_rate)
        onset_strength_mean = np.mean(onset_strength) if onset_strength.size > 0 else 0
    
        # Harmonicity
        harmonic = librosa.effects.harmonic(y=audio)
        harmonic_mean = np.mean(harmonic) if harmonic.size > 0 else 0
    
        # Jitter and shimmer
        fundamental_freqs, _ = librosa.piptrack(y=audio, sr=sample_rate)
        fundamental_freqs = fundamental_freqs[fundamental_freqs > 0]
        jitter = np.std(fundamental_freqs) / np.mean(fundamental_freqs) if len(fundamental_freqs) > 0 else 0
    
        amplitude = np.abs(audio)
        shimmer = np.std(amplitude) / np.mean(amplitude) if len(amplitude) > 0 else 0
    
        # Combine features
        combined_features = np.hstack((
            mfccs_scaled,
            mel_spectrogram_scaled,
            [pitch_freq, onset_strength_mean, harmonic_mean, jitter, shimmer]
        ))
    
        # Extract XLS-R embeddings
        inputs = processor(audio, sampling_rate=16000, return_tensors="pt", padding=True)
        with torch.no_grad():
            xlsr_embeddings = model_wav2vec(**inputs).last_hidden_state.mean(dim=1).squeeze().numpy()
    
        # Concatenate all features
        final_features = np.hstack((combined_features, xlsr_embeddings))
    
        # Normalize final features
        return (final_features - np.mean(final_features)) / np.std(final_features)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error encountered while parsing file: {file_name}, {e}")
        return None

# Load and process data

     file_path = r"C:\Users\INDIA\Desktop\dissertation\CVoiceFake_small\sample\labels.csv"
     data = pd.read_csv(file_path)

# Encode the categorical data

    le_detection = LabelEncoder()
    data['detection'] = le_detection.fit_transform(data['detection'])

# Extract features using the filenames from the 'Audio' column

    data['features'] = data['Audio'].apply(lambda x: extract_features(x))

# Replace missing features with the mean value of each feature column

    features_array = np.array(data['features'].tolist())

means = np.nanmean(features_array, axis=0)
data\['features'\] = data\['features'\].apply(lambda x: np.nan_to_num(x, nan=means))

# Ensure there are valid features before proceeding

if data.empty:
print("No valid audio files processed. Check the file paths and formats.")
else:
\# Convert features to numpy array
X = np.array(data\['features'\].tolist())
y = np.array(data\['detection'\].tolist())

    # Dimensionality Reduction (optional)
    pca = PCA(n_components=0.95)  # Retain 95% of variance
    X_reduced = pca.fit_transform(X)
    
    # Expand dimensions for LSTM
    X_reduced = np.expand_dims(X_reduced, axis=-1)
    
    # Split the data into training and testing sets with stratification
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_reduced, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42, stratify=y)
    
    # Build the LSTM model
    input_audio = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]))  # (timesteps, features)
    
    # Audio feature layers
    x = LSTM(128, return_sequences=True)(input_audio)  
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = LSTM(64)(x)  
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    x = Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
    
    # Final output layer
    output = Dense(2, activation='softmax')(x)  
    
    model = Model(inputs=input_audio, outputs=output)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.001))
    
    # Early stopping to prevent overfitting
    early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=10, restore_best_weights=True)
    
    # Train the model
    model.fit(X_train, to_categorical(y_train), epochs=50, batch_size=32, validation_data=(X_test, to_categorical(y_test)), callbacks=[early_stopping])
    
    # Evaluate the model
    train_loss, train_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_train, to_categorical(y_train), verbose=0)
    print(f"Training accuracy: {train_accuracy * 100:.2f}%")
    
    test_loss, test_accuracy = model.evaluate(X_test, to_categorical(y_test), verbose=0)
    print(f"Test accuracy: {test_accuracy * 100:.2f}%")
    
    # Detailed evaluation
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
    y_pred_classes = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)
    y_true = np.argmax(to_categorical(y_test), axis=1)
    
    print("Classification Report:\n", classification_report(y_true, y_pred_classes))
    
    conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred_classes)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
    sns.heatmap(conf_matrix, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap='Blues', xticklabels=['Class 0', 'Class 1'], yticklabels=['Class 0', 'Class 1'])
    plt.xlabel('Predicted Labels')
    plt.ylabel('True Labels')
    plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
    plt.show()


I want to get accuracy of the model in predicting if the audio is fake or real.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How to get an output for the code? It has been running non stop without giving any output. I have made the code for deepfake audio detection . Is there anything you can do to help

I am trying to build a multilingual pretrained model for deepfake audio detection on multiple languages, and XLS-R has been running without giving any output, it doesnt even show any error, what can i do to fix this
